# Overloading unapply and subclasses

Tags: scala

Normally, if we have an extractor whose parameter is of type `A` and we're using it to match an object of type `B >: A`, the object will be first checked if it's an instance of `A` before being passed to the extractor's `unapply`:

```
trait Foo
class SomeFoo extends Foo

object FooBar {
  def unapply(foo: SomeFoo) = true
}

def foo(foo: Foo): Unit = foo match {
  case FooBar() => println("ok")
}
```

Calling `foo(new SomeFoo)` should print `ok`.

But if we overload method `unapply` in FooBar, it no longer works:

```
object Test {

  trait Foo
  class SomeFoo extends Foo

  trait Bar
  class SomeBar extends Bar

  object FooBar {
    def unapply(foo: SomeFoo) = true
    def unapply(bar: SomeBar) = true
  }

  def foo(foo: Foo): Unit = foo match {
    case FooBar() => println("foo")
    case _        =>
  }

  def bar(bar: Bar): Unit = bar match {
    case FooBar() => println("bar")
    case _        =>
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    foo(new SomeFoo)
    bar(new SomeBar)
  }
}
```

We get an error:

```
overloaded method value unapply with alternatives:
 (bar: Test.SomeBar)Boolean <and>
 (foo: Test.SomeFoo)Boolean
cannot be applied to (Test.Foo)
    case FooBar() => println("foo")
```

And similar for `Bar`.

Removing either of the `unapply` methods or changing the types of parameters in `foo` and `bar` to `SomeFoo` and `SomeBar` fixes it.

Why is that? Shouldn't the compiler be able to pick the right method? I understand that overloading `unapply` might be problematic when it could cause ambiguity (e.g. `unapply(Foo)` vs. `unapply(SomeFoo)`), but it is not the case here.

I want to do something like this:

```
trait Term
case class Var(name: String) extends Term
case class Lambda(x: Var, e: Term) extends Term
case class Apply(f: Term, a: Term) extends Term

trait TypedTerm
case class TypedVar(name: String) extends TypedTerm
case class AnnotatedVar(v: TypedVar, t: Type) extends TypedTerm
case class TypedLambda(x: AnnotatedVar, e: TypedTerm) extends TypedTerm
case class TypedApply(f: TypedTerm, a: TypedTerm) extends TypedTerm

object !: {
  def unapply(t: TypedLambda) = TypedLambda.unapply(t)
  def unapply(t: Lambda) = Lambda.unapply(t)
}

object % {
  def unapply(t: TypedApply) = TypedApply.unapply(t)
  def unapply(t: Apply) = Apply.unapply(t)
}

object :: {
  def unapply(v: AnnotatedVar) = AnnotatedVar.unapply(v)
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
term match {
  case x !: e => // ...
  case f % a => // ...
}

typedTerm match {
  case (x :: t) !: e => // ...
  case f % a => // ...
}
```

Maybe there is a different solution?

Comment: `def unapply(t: Any) = t match { case _: TypedLambda => TypedLambda.unapply(t); ...}` ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know how I haven't come up with this...